# 4 GPIO 16 Mosfets

Tags: mosfet, spi, gpio

I have 4 GPIO's and I have to drive 16 mosfets for my application.

MCU -> 4 GPIO -> something must be here(SPI mosfet driver??) -> 16 mosfets

I thought that if I have an SPI mosfet gate driver IC, I can drive 16 mosfets by using 4 GPIO's. If I write my own SPI function.

But I dont know if there is an IC that can drive mosfet's gates by SPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a shift register (for example 74HC595) to drive the MOSFET gates. You can drive that chip with four GPIO lines (DATA, CLOCK, LATCH, ENABLE).

Answer (score 5):

The general term is "IO expander". This sort of thing:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21952a.pdf

Although you can also do it with a [shift register](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut): cheaper, and may have higher drive strength.